# Calling a function by checking a checkbox JQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am new at Jquery and was hoping for some advice as to how to call a jQuery function using a check box.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkBestSeller']", function () {

    alert("Thanks for checking me");

});

<input type='checkbox' name='chkBestSeller' value='Best Seller'/>
```

At the moment, it is not working.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/HETuH/

Comment: Did you put the Javascript code within the `<script></script>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="chkBestSeller"]').click(function () {

    alert("Thanks for checking me");

});
```

Answer (score 9):

Use change with checkboxes:

```
$('input[name="chkBestSeller"]').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("Thanks for checking me");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='isSelected'/>

$('#isSelected').bind('change', function () {

   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     alert("Checked");
   else
     alert("Unchecked");

});
```